# How do I construct ticks and labels when ploting large temporal series with matplotlib where the dates are a str column?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I have a pandas data series to display that contains basically a temporal series where each observation is contained in `df['date']` (x-axis) and `df['value']` (y-axis):

```
df['date']

0       2004-01-02
1       2004-01-05
2       2004-01-06
3       2004-01-07
4       2004-01-08
           ...    
4527    2021-12-27
4528    2021-12-28
4529    2021-12-29
4530    2021-12-30
4531    2021-12-31
Name: session, Length: 4532, dtype: object
```

Notice how the Series contains `str` types:

```
print(type(df['date'].values[0]))

<class 'str'>
```

`df['values']` are just integers.

---

If I plot the series using matplotlib and try to use `df['date']` I obtain a too dense chart where the `xtick labels` can not be read:

```
ax.plot(df['date'], df['value']);
```

[image: Dense Plot]

If I want to display xticks on every month change (so 2004/01, 2004/02, .... 2021/11, 2021/12) and labels just when the year changes (2004, 2005, ... 2021), which would be the best way to accomplish that either via numpy or pandas to get the arrays that `.set_xticks` require?

Comment: Convert the `date` column [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and use the [`matplotlib.dates`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/dates_api.html) locators (e.g., `MonthLocator` each month for minor ticks, `YearLocator` each year for major ticks).

Answer (score 0):

Just to further elaborate on tdy's comment (all credit on the answer to tdy), this is the code excerpt to implement `to_datetime` and use the locators:

```
ax.plot(pd.to_datetime(df['date']), df['value'])
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.YearLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y'))
```